# Loading jquery elements with ajax pagination in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have implemented the following railscast for my project :- http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=asciicast . I have been able to make this work seamlessly with a few changes as well. Now, I am trying to add a slideshow (using zurb-foundation carousel) to each of my products element. The problem I am facing is that when the first time the page loads, the slide show works perfectly. However, when I click on any of the pagination/sort/search links, the slideshow gets converted into plain images (jquery component is not loaded).

I am not sure what I am missing.

Here's my code snippet :-

**Products.js**

```
$("div.slideshow_list_page").orbit({animation: 'fade',                  // fade,     horizontal-slide, vertical-slide, horizontal-push
  animationSpeed: 800,                // how fast animtions are
  timer: false,                        // true or false to have the timer
  resetTimerOnClick: false,           // true resets the timer instead of pausing        slideshow progress
  advanceSpeed: 4000,                 // if timer is enabled, time between transitions
  pauseOnHover: false,                // if you hover pauses the slider
  startClockOnMouseOut: false,        // if clock should start on MouseOut
  startClockOnMouseOutAfter: 1000,    // how long after MouseOut should the timer start again
  directionalNav: true,               // manual advancing directional navs
  captions: false,                     // do you want captions?
  captionAnimation: 'fade',           // fade, slideOpen, none
  captionAnimationSpeed: 800,         // if so how quickly should they animate in
  bullets: true,                     // true or false to activate the bullet navigation
  bulletThumbs: false,                // thumbnails for the bullets
  bulletThumbLocation: '',            // location from this file where thumbs will be
  afterSlideChange: function(){},     // empty function
  fluid: true}         );
```

**application.js**

```
$(function () {
  $('#products th a, #products .apple_pagination a').live('click', function () {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

**products.html.erb**

```
<td><div class="slideshow_list_page">
<%=  image_tag "logo.png" %>
<%=  image_tag "rails.png" %>
</div>
</td>
```

thanks,
Amit